# ¿Como registrar un historial de actividades de un usuario loggeado en sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, webservice

Quisiera saber si hay algún método para poder registrar las actividades que hace un usuario loggeado en un sistema y registrar sus actividades en una base de datos de sql server mediante un stored procedure, me explico:

- Si el usuario loggeado hace click en un botón, que me registre automáticamente un log en la base de datos, que registre el nombre de usuario, hora y fecha, y en que botón hizo click
- o Si el usuario loggeado ingresa a una pantalla, que me registre el nombre de usuario, hora y fecha, y a que pantalla ingreso

espero haberme explicado, y sus ayudas me serán de muy buena utilidad

gracias!!

Comment: que tipo de desarrollo de interfaz de usuario estas implementando?

Comment: qué has intentado? que código tienes? tendrías que hacer alguna tabla log, en la que, al menos, tengas una fk con el ID usuario, una descripción de la acción, y la fecha, en la que tendrías que insertar cada vez que haga algo en el sistema. Adicionalmente, creo que tu log sería más útil al momento de ver quién modifica o crea registros, pero pues lo que digo es parafrasear, no sé que alcance tengas con tu sistema.

Comment: estoy utilizando formulario web forms (.aspx) MVC, WPF, aun no tengo código apenas empezare con este requerimiento, quisiera saber como poder empezar o algún ejemplo de código para poder guiarme y llevar acabo esta actividad

Comment: eso si lo tengo entendido que hay que crear una tabla LOG donde me registre el log con los datos que voy a registrar

Comment: pero sobre que tecnologia implementaras la UI del usuario? porque aspx, asp.net mvc o wpf no tienes nada que ver una con otra

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo básico de lo que se tendría que hacer para capturar lo que quieres. También depende de como estés escribiendo el código en tu base de datos.

Para empezar, declaré 3 tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Objetos(
    IdObjeto        int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    NombreObjeto    varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    TipoObjeto      varchar(50) NOT NULL, --También puede tener su tabla
    RutaObjeto      varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Objeto PRIMARY KEY (IdObjeto),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_Objeto UNIQUE (NombreObjeto, RutaObjeto) --No puede haber dos objetos con la misma ubicación
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Acciones(
    IdAccion        int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    NombreAcccion   varchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Accion PRIMARY KEY (IdAccion)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.LogUsuario(
    Fecha           datetime,
    IdUsuario       int, --
    IdObjeto        int,
    IdAccion        int
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_LogUsuario ON dbo.LogUsuario( Fecha, IdUsuario);
```

Después creo un Procedimiento Almacenado para guardar la información

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RegistrarAccionUsuario(
    @IdUsuario      int,
    @NombreObjeto   varchar(100),
    @RutaObjeto     varchar(1000),
    @NombreAccion   varchar(50)
)
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.LogUsuario(
    Fecha,
    IdUsuario,
    IdObjeto,
    IdAccion
)
SELECT GETDATE(),
    @IdUsuario,
    o.IdObjeto,
    a.IdAccion
FROM Objetos o
CROSS JOIN Acciones a
WHERE o.NombreObjeto = @NombreObjeto
AND o.RutaObjeto = @RutaObjeto
AND a.NombreAcccion = @NombreAccion;
```

Con esto, sólo tienes que llamar el procedimiento cada vez que ocurra una acción.

Por ser un log de uso del sistema, prefiero que quede lo más compacto posible ya que son las tablas que más crecen dentro de una base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme con ese código!! lo intentare haber que tal me va, gracias!!